# PHP/JS: Posting input value with js function and echoing through php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My goal is to have input field that will take value of whats was typed and echoed through. The js function will grab the value of the input box two seconds after user stops typing and post it. The issue seems to be with the php not echoing the value of the input box. When I take out the js function and use a button that forces refresh then
it works fine. How come php is not taking the value posted by js function?

[Example SITE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/youtube_video/)

**JS**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                    var timer;
                                        $('#video-input1').on('keyup', function() {
                                            var value = this.value;

                                            clearTimeout(timer);

                                            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                                                //do your submit here
                                                $("#ytVideo").submit()

                                                //alert('submitted:' + value);
                                            }, 2000);
                                        });


                 //then include your submit definition. What you want to do once submit is executed
                  $('#ytVideo').submit(function(e){
                       e.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
                       var form = $('#ytVideo').serialize();
                       //submit.php is the page where you submit your form
                       $.post('index.php', form, function(data){ 

                       });
                      return false;

                  }); 


            });
            </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    if($_POST)
    {
        $url     = $_POST['yurl'];


        function getYoutubeVideoID($url) {
            $formatted_url = preg_replace('~https?://(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com\S*[^\w\-\s])([\w\-]{11})      
                    (?=[^\w\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>| </a>))[?=&+%\w-]*~ix','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1',$url);
            return $formatted_url;
        }
        $formatted_url = getYoutubeVideoID($url);
        $parsed_url = parse_url($formatted_url);




        parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_query_string);
        $v = $parsed_query_string['v'];

        $hth        = 300; //$_POST['yheight'];
        $wdth       = 500; //$_POST['ywidth'];
        $is_auto    =   0;


//Iframe code with optional autoplay

echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$v.'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');

}
?>
```

**form**

```
<html>
    <form  method="post" id="ytVideo" action="">
    Youtube URL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="video-input1" type="text" value="<?php $url ?>" name="yurl">   
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Embed Code" name="ysubmit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not returning your php result anywhere. It's simply lost...

```
$.post('index.php', form, function(data){ 
    var x = $(data);
    $("body").html(x);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did try it but it makes the whole page go blank after input in text box. you can check the [SITE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/youtube_video/)